# Stop Power Automate from escaping backslash

Tags: escaping, power-automate, backslash

I am using a flow that was working fine a few months ago. It includes an HTTP Get call with basic authentication. The username includes a backslash (e.g. test\login).

But whenever I add this loging as a variable, even if I key it manually in the username field of the HTTP action automate is adding a second backslasg. So the username being sent is test\login which is causing the API not to work.

How do I avoid this please?

I tried using compose to build the username, but it simply replaces \ with \ (double backslash).

Comment: Where are you seeing the double backslash? If you are looking a the output in the flow run, then note it is showing it in JSON format and a ``\`` is encoded as ``\\``.

Comment: Yes, I am seeing it in the raw output, both of the PowerApps V2 trigger (where the username is first passed) and also in the HTTP Show Raw Inputs. Note that I have tried to input the username directly in the Username field of the HTTP action, and also tried with concat and various other options

Comment: The API is working as when I input the same URL, Username and Password from Postman I am getting the required response

Comment: I'm fairly sure the double slash is only flow showing it encoded in JSON and that it isn't being sent that way. What response do you get? 403? I wonder if URL Encoding helps `%5C` (doubt it). Sure it isn't password or leading/trailing spaces? Would like to see your output but probably to sensitive to share.

Comment: I think @SamNseir is right, and in fact I am now checking further in the API... possibly there is an issue of black listing which is blocking my requests to get to the API... as in fact I am not getting any sort of response... just retries without any response.